# $_POST variables not passed by form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm hosting a simple contact form on App Engine using PHP, trying to pass $_POST variables from a form to a PHP script that sends the email. As I can read from the logs, the $_POST variables don't seem to get through and I struggle to understand why... hence would appreciate another pair of eyes on this... thank you. Here are the various bits of (simplified) code:

Within index.html at the root:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="contactform">
<div>
<label for="email">Enter your email</label>
<input type="text" class="input-field" id="email" name="email" value="">
</div>
<a id="button-send" href="#" title="Send Email" class="button" style="width:100%;">Send E-Mail</a>
<div id="success">Your message has been sent successfully!</div>
<div id="error">Unable to send your message, please try later.</div>
</form>
```

The PHP file, also at the root:

```
<?php 
$send_email_to = "test@test.com";
$email_subject = "Email subject line";

function send_email($email,$email_message)
{
// using AppEngine's mail function here
}

function validate($email,$message)
{
// a simple validation function
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
$email = $_POST['email']; // this doesn't seem to work
}
else
{$email = "email@email.com";} // did this to confirm the $_POST didn't seem to be passed

$return_array = validate($email,$message);

if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
send_email(,$email,$message);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();
?>
```

And the javascript that controls the error messages:

```
$('#button-send').click(function(event){
    $('#button-send').html('Sending message...');
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').scrollTo( $('#contact'), 'fast' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_form_email.php',
        data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
            if(html.success == '1')
            {
                $('#button-send').html('Send message');
                $('#success').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#button-send').html('Send message');
                $('#error').show();
            }                   
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#button-send').html('Send message');
            $('#error').show();
        }
    });
```

And in case this has to do with App Engine, my app.yaml looks like this:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /send_form_email.php*
  script: send_form_email.php

- url: .*
  script: index.html
```

Many thanks again – I've also put the full code on my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4yzSrEzbZ5jbk1oc2RWb2xSRWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The `action="#"` looks a little suspicious. Try to change it to something else.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen the OP is posting via the ajax call so the action on the form doesn't matter, it's during his ajax call that the problem occurs. The $("contact_form").serialize() should be $("contactform").serialize();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to serialise `#contact_form` but you have `id="contactform"`

The MIME type for JSON is `application/json`, not `text/json`.

Comment: Ah yes, that worked, thanks. Just have one more error with the header: "PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" despite the email being properly sent but my Javascript messages aren't therefore updated.